# Returning pointer error from a function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am sending 2 strings to a function with pointers, and I expect one of them to change when they get back to main function. but it just returns null, as it shouldn't.

```
int main (){
...
char *str1="SOME RANDOM INPUT";
char *str2=NULL;
function1 (str1, str2);
...
}

void function1 (char mystr, char *output){
 char *input = strtok(mystr, " ");
 if (input != NULL)
      output = input;

 return;
}
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: oh, completely mistaken the variable names. sorry. editing now

Comment: Do not change the string literal.

Comment: strtok to change the string.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you said, I'm not changing anything with strtok?

Comment: `strtok("SOME RANDOM INPUT", " ")` change `"SOME RANDOM INPUT"` to  `"SOME\0RANDOM INPUT"`. change string literal. UB.

Comment: oh, I got it now. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should work with pointers to pointers to get the pointer changed, like that:

```
int main (){
...
char *str1="SOME RANDOM INPUT";
char *str2=NULL;
function1 (&str1, &str2);
...
}

void function1 (char **input, char **output){
 ...
 if (*input != NULL)
      *output = *input;

 return;
}
```

Comment: The underlying reason, of course, is that changes in a local function parameter does not change its "original" value.

Comment: Indeed, it is. In C++ there is a possibility to mark a function parameter as a reference, but C doesn't have that.

Answer (score 2):

You should always have in mind that C, pass the parameters always by value and not by reference.

Show for example assume that with the code

`char *str1="SOME RANDOM INPUT";`

`str1`holds a memory location e.g. 0x008000

when you call `function1 (str1, str2);` the memory location of `str1` will be **copied** to the parameter variable `input`, whose scope is restricted inside the scope of the function of course. `input` has the same contents with `str1` but they are placed in completely different memory locations. So by altering `input` value you do not affect `str1`.

The solution is to use double pointer. (In C++ you could use call by reference with the & operator)